How to prevent C++ macro from substituting a class member?
I am building a Linux kernel module, the source code is C++ based.
One of the src files named A.cpp always has a build failure.
A.cpp indirectly includes two header files: asm/current.h and bits/stl_iterator.h in sequence.
There is a macro definition in asm/current.h:
#define current get_current()

Meanwhile, there is a C++ class definition in bits/stl_iterator.h:
 template<typename _Iterator>
    class reverse_iterator
    {
    protected:
      _Iterator current;
      ...
    public:
      ...
      _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR
      reverse_iterator() : current() { }
    }

Unfortunately, the current within the C++ class gets substituted by get_current() at the preprocessing stage, consequently there are syntax errors reported at the compiling stage.
So, is there any method to fix the issue without changing the two header files? They are provided by standard C++ library or Linux kernel source code.
To avoid the issue, I know we may use #undef current, or change the include order, but it should not be a reasonable solution to the issue.

Not sure what you might change... but wrapping problematic header with appropriate #undef seems fine to me.

Is this your own code?  Are you able to change the order of these two includes?

"I know we may use "#undef current" or change the including order to avoid the issue, but it should not be a reasonable solution to the issue." Why it is not reasonable?

Is it possible to reverse the order of the includes?  First include all the standard header files and then include the asm/current.h last.  Or replace asm/current.h with a header file of your own (a copy) and take out this evil #define and then fix the code to call get_current() explicitly

Ain't macros a stinker?

This is why macros should be avoided whenever possible - they're very primitive and cause all kinds of problems.  And those problems can be hard to avoid.

asm/current.h is included if the macro __ASSEMBLY__ is undefined. You can #define __ASSEMBLY__ on top of A.cpp.
I agree with the comments, the best solution is
// A.cpp
// #include system/linux files here

#undef current

// #include C++ files here

